# HTML and JQuery files not communicating

Tags: jquery, html

I'm just starting off trying to teach myself some basic jQuery and HTML. I took some of the codecademy courses and am trying some things out myself. I have an .html file that sets up 5 input variables, a button, and a table. I am trying to enter values into the inputs and on button click replace the existing values in the table with the new values. When I open up the html file locally it seems to load up fine. I enter in the values but the script doesn't seem to be calling the .js file code because nothing happens.

Website.html code

```
<!DOCType html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Enter Values</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    </head> 
    <form>
    BusID: <input type="text" name="busId" value="Enter BusID">
    xCord: <input type="text" name="xCord" value="Enter xCords">
    yCord: <input type="text" name="yCord" value="Enter yCords">
    timeStamp: <input type="text" name="timeStamp" value="Enter Time Stamp">
    eventType: <input type="text" name="eventType" value="Enter Event Type">
    </form>
    <button>Click Me!</button><br/>
    <body>
        <table id="tableClassName">
            <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <div>
    </div>
</html>
```

----jquery.js file code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var busId = $("input[name=busId]").val();
        var xCord = $("input[name=xCord]").val();
        var yCord = $("input[name=yCord]")val();
        var timeStamp = $("input[name=timeStamp]").val();
        var eventType = $("input[name=eventType]").val();
        $('#tableClassName').html("<tr>""<td>"+busId+"</td>""<td>"+xCord+"</td>""<td>"+yCord+"</td>""<td>"+timeStamp+"</td>""<td>"+eventType+"</td>""</tr>");
    })
})
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?  And did you happen to get any warnings about blocked content?

Comment: Go to your browser's developer tools and see what errors (if any) the console is showing. That should point you in the right direction. Also why do you have a form and button outside of your `body` tags?

Comment: Two things. First your form and button are outside of the body tag (needs to be within it). Two, when debugging JavaScript, use the browser's developer tools (press F12) and console.

Comment: FYI: It seems like you are missing a dot. `var yCord = $("input[name=yCord]")val();`

Comment: One more thing, don't forget to run your code through a validator to help find errors. http://validator.w3.org/ is a great one.

Comment: 1st. Check the comment from Mikael Dúi Bolinder.
If it doesn't help, look at Zach Spencer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery library. Add this to your head to use google's hosted version:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or download your own version and link to it. jQuery isn't an inherent part of javascript and must be included.

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to the group... seems like I can only respond to individual replys? Anyway, thank you everyone for your help. After running debugger in IE I get this error message:

SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
jquery.js, line 1 character 1

Comment: @user3298335 have you added in the code in my answer? It is undefined because you haven't included the jQuery library.

Comment: Yes I had added it, but I actually just found the issue as I was double checking I didn't copy/paste it wrong or something. I had to add "http:" to your src and then now it works. Thanks!!!

Comment: @user3298335 ok, I'll change my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you miss the jQuery core JavaScript files.

Include this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes? OP is clearly missing the jQuery files!

Comment: I'm not sure myself. Maybe because you didn't include how to?

Comment: @nevermind: the source of it is shown by OP... Clearly not jQuery core js.

Comment: Yes, btw, didn't voted down your answer (and usually i don't do it).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jquery source files. Here is how your html page should look

```
<!DOCType html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Enter Values</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    </head> 
    <form>
    BusID: <input type="text" name="busId" value="Enter BusID">
    xCord: <input type="text" name="xCord" value="Enter xCords">
    yCord: <input type="text" name="yCord" value="Enter yCords">
    timeStamp: <input type="text" name="timeStamp" value="Enter Time Stamp">
    eventType: <input type="text" name="eventType" value="Enter Event Type">
    </form>
    <button>Click Me!</button><br/>
    <body>
        <table id="tableClassName">
            <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <div>
    </div>
</html>
```